# Conectar jdbc sqlserver en soapui MockService

Tags: sql-server, webservice, jdbc, groovy, soapui

Al realizar una conexión a sql server en un MockService utilizando soapui version 5.4 me aparece el siguiente error:

> INFO:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:
>   connectionUrl for class: Script1

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.Driver

def holderDataXml= new XmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent)
try {
def db = [url:'jdbc:sqlserver://'+ /name1\name2:1433/+ '/Database', user:'user', password:'password']

def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

} catch (Exception e) 
{
    log.info e
    context.ResultResponse = "Invalid Xml"
}
```

No se que me puede estar fallando o faltando, de pronto un import.

Comment: [soapUI accede a MS SQL DB desde Groovy Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4792579/8933039), [SoapUI + sqlite-jdbc = ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778854/8933039), [How to connect to sql DB from soapUI using connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33569837/8933039), [Solved JDBC Cannot connect to a MS SQL database](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Solved-JDBC-Cannot-connect-to-a-MS-SQL-database/td-p/132235), [How to create a MSSQL server connection in SOAPUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36822071/8933039)

Comment: [Testing JDBC Databases](https://www.soapui.org/jdbc/testing-jdbc-databases.html) Quizás encuentre la solución en uno de esos enlaces